# How do I pass the reference of an instance from a class with a constrained parameter type, to an instance of that constraint type?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have these two classes:

```cs
public abstract class ASpawnedObject {}
```

```cs
public abstract class ASpawner<T> where T : ASpawnedObject {}
```

The `ASpawner` class creates some `ASpawnedObject` instances. I want it to pass itself to the `ASpawnedObject` constructor and keep a reference of it as a member variable:

```cs
public abstract class ASpawnedObject {}
{
    ASpawner<ASpawnedObject> spawner;

    public void Init(ASpawner<ASpawnedObject> spawner)
    {
        this.spawner = spawner;
    }
}
```

```cs
public abstract class ASpawner<T> where T : ASpawnedObject
{
    public void Spawn()
    {
        T spawnedObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        spawnedObject.Init(this);
    }
}
```

BUT: `spawnedObject.Init(this)` is causing a conversion error in `ASpawner`. It can't convert `ASpawner<T>` to `ASpawner<ASpawnedObject>` even with the type constraint. I don't get it. Doesn't it follow the polymorphism principles?

Comment: `new ASpawnedObject(this)` doesn't occur in the code you've shown. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet done, I hope it’s enough. Sorry for that.

Comment: The problem is that a `Generic<SomeBaseClass>` is not the same as `Generic<SomeDerivingClass>`. Lets say we have a base class `Animal` and two classes deriving from it `Fish` and `Bird`. Now you would agree that you can't add a `Bird` to a `List<Fish>`. However if the conversion you're asking for was allowed, I could do `List<Animal> animals = new List<Fish>();` and then do `animals.Add(new Bird());` breaking the type safe system. Same logic is what is preventing your conversion.

Comment: Also, `new ASpawnedObject(this)` will not work because ASpawnedObject is abstract.

Comment: @Knoop yes, I've heard about that case. But doesn't the constraint make `ASpawnedObject` the base class of anything that could replace `T`?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes thank you, this is just a bad simplification, I’m correcting it.

Comment: Yes it does make `ASpawnedObject` the base class of anything that could replace `T` however in the constructor of `ASpawnedObject` you ask for the specific `ASpawner<ASpawnedObject>` so the constructor requires that specific version (and for the reasons mentioned above you can't pass any `ASpawner<TDerivedSpawnedObject>` to that constructor because they're not the same thing.

Comment: No, your question still says that an expression `new ASpawnedObject(this)` is causing a problem, but that expression still isn't in your code anywhere. Currently you'll have a compile-time error because `Activator.CreateInstance` is declared to return `object`, so you'd need to cast the result... but that's not what your question *says* causes the problem. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @JonSkeet I’m working in a Unity Engine environment, and thus this code is a translation in pure .NET, but I’m not doing it very well. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Rather than translate it, just show the exact code you've got and explain that it's in Unity. Given that you (and we) don't know the problem, it's best to present it with as little translation as possible, to avoid mutating the problem along the way

Comment: @Knoop I think I get your point. I’ll try to find a workaround, but I feel like generics might not be the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test class compiles and runs without any exceptions

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void X()
    {
        var ghostSpawner = new GhostSpawner();
        ghostSpawner.Spawn();
    }
}
```

What you have to do is constrain your spawner and your spawned object in terms of your spawned object. Yes, that means for the latter, in terms of itself:

```
public abstract class ASpawnedObject<T> where T : ASpawnedObject<T>
{
    ASpawner<T> spawner;
    public void Init(ASpawner<T> spawner) => this.spawner = spawner;
}

public abstract class ASpawner<T> where T : ASpawnedObject<T>
{
    public void Spawn()
    {
        T spawnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        spawnedObject.Init(this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, that means the `ASpawnedObject` base class must be made generic. You can then create non-generic concrete classes that make the test pass.

```
public class GhostSpawner : ASpawner<Ghost>
{}

public class Ghost : ASpawnedObject<Ghost>
{}
```

Comment: I didn’t even try that, thinking it would be silly... Thank you, you solved it.